# Visual Studio User Contol Design

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-designer

If you have a user control with a field like `public int number = 10;` can you make that value come up in the properties box when you use the designer in VS 2010 and C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn your variable into a property.  Try adding Get Set and sometimes you have to add the proper attributes (referencing the System.ComponentModel class)

```
private int _Number = 10;

[DefaultValue(10)]
[Description("This is a number.")]
public int Number
{
  get { return _Number; }
  set { _Number = value; }
}
```

Note: The DefaultValue attribute is for setting the designer to bold or not.  It doesn't actually *set* the default value.

Comment: You only need to apply the Browsable attribute with (false) if you want to HIDE a public property from the property inspector.

Comment: What about hiding a default property like BorderStyle or something?

Comment: @Mark Different question.  You would have to override the property and add the Browsable(false) attribute yourself.

Comment: Ok sounds simple enough will accept this answer cause it was first

Answer (score 2):

using System.ComponentModel;

```
[Browsable(true)]
public bool SampleProperty { get; set; }
```

and if you want the property under a category

```
[Category("My Properties")] 
public string MyCustomProperty{ get; set; }
```